# Merge last two commits into one with reset

Tags: git

I have to merge last two commits in branch "master" into one with command reset, but I couldn't find how to do this. I have only found solution with rebase, but it didn't work properly for me.
I will be really glad for any help, thank you!

Here are last two commits if it will be useful:

```
commit c6757068ca0768eb7afadb6a87d43fb4f3967d1b
Author: Name <mail>
Date:   Wed Jun 1 00:13:47 2016 +0200

    Add name to copyright

commit 476dae7afcd9f143bb48f932f1281c21d872ebb0
Author: Name <mail>
Date:   Wed Jun 1 00:13:11 2016 +0200

    Add tag <i> on line 13
```

Comment: `git rebase` is the way to go.  Exactly what did you try?

Comment: There is another option. `git branch tmp;git reset HEAD~2 --hard;git merge tmp --squash;git add .;git commit;` This is usually used when you want to merge the new commits of one branch as one commit into another branch.

Answer (score 3):

If you'd like to give the rebasing approach another shot, use `git rebase -i HEAD~2`. Then, using the command line tool, squash the most recent commit into the older one by replacing the newer commit's “pick” command with “squash”.

Alternatively, assuming your working directory is clean, try `git reset --soft HEAD~2`, then make a brand new commit.  The contents of that commit will be the same as the two most-recent commits that you're trying to merge into one.